# Close Office applications (Word, Excel, Outlook) before install an Office 2007 Add-in

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ms-office, setup-project

How can I close any Office 2007 running application like Word,Excel,Outlook before installing an Office 2007 Add-in in a Visual Studio 2008 Setup Project?

Thanks!
Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/eric_carter/archive/2009/03/12/attaching-to-an-already-running-office-application-from-your-application-using-getactiveobject-or-bindtomoniker.aspx) for sample code of how to attach to a running instance of Excel, enabling you to manipulate it (including terminating the instance). See [here](http://blocko.blogspot.com/2006/10/driving-excel-and-powerpoint-with-c.html) for sample code of getting the RunningObjectTable, used to get all instances of a specified application.